# list index out of range when using map()

Tags: python, list, dictionary, indexing, split

I tried to use the map function with 1 pre-desined function and 1 parameter. Everything works fine till I call list() on map function. In the end it shows

> IndexError: list index out of range

But when I simply call the function on the list without using map(), it was okay. Can anyone try and help me identify the bug?

---

```
people = ['Dr. Christopher Brooks', 'Dr. Kevyn Collins-Thompson', 'Dr. VG Vinod Vydiswaran', 'Dr. Daniel Romero']

def split_title_and_name(person):

    name_list=[]

    for i in person:
        i = i.split()[0]+" "+i.split()[-1]
        name_list.append(i)

    return name_list 

split_title_and_name(people)
list(map(split_title_and_name, people))
```

Comment: Can you fix your indentation. `map` takes each individual person and applies the function `split_title_and_name()`. `split_title_and_name('Dr. Chistopher Brooks')` is very different from sending a list of names.

Comment: You function seems designed for taking the iterable of names *directly*. It will of course throw an error if you `map` it on to `people` because when you iterate `for i in person` it iterates over the individual *characters* of a *single name*. When `i` reaches the space `" "` then `split` returns and empty list `[]` and indexing into an empty list will throw the `IndexError`

Answer (score 1):

Those are not the same functionality.  Your function operates on a list of people.  **map** applies the function to each *element* of **people**.  Thus, you're calling

```
split_title_and_name('Dr. Christopher Brooks')
split_title_and_name('Dr. Kevyn Collins-Thompson')
...
```

See the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Your function `split_title_and_name` works on a list of people, when you want it to work on one person at a time:

```
def split_title_and_name(person):
    return person.split()[0] + " " + person.split()[-1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a better Solution:

```
    people = ['Dr. Christopher Brooks', 'Dr. Kevyn Collins-Thompson', 'Dr. VG Vinod Vydiswaran', 'Dr. Daniel Romero']

def split_title_and_name(person):
    title = person.split()[0]
    lastname = person.split()[-1]
    return '{} {}'.format(title, lastname)

list(map(split_title_and_name, people))
```

it looks less complex when I used format function.

Answer (score 0):

just in case you intend to use the function on "heavylifting" and wish to avoid repeated split calls... perhaps you should try to store first the splitted string... try :-)

```
people = ['Dr. Christopher Brooks', 'Dr. Kevyn Collins-Thompson', 'Dr. VG Vinod Vydiswaran', 'Dr. Daniel Romero']

def split_title_and_name(person):

    splitted_string = people.split() 
    title = splitted_string[0]
    lastname = splitted_string[-1]
    return '{} {}'.format(title, lastname)

list(map(split_title_and_name, people))
```